# How do i fix my scrolling to snap align while having orbit controls?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a three.js website and i want the page to scroll snap to the start of the page but since i have orbit controls scrolling on touch devices doesnt work so i came up with

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });


document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

var xDown = null;                                                        
var yDown = null;

function getTouches(evt) {
  return evt.touches ||             // browser API
         evt.originalEvent.touches; // jQuery
}                                                     
                                                                         
function handleTouchStart(evt) {
    const firstTouch = getTouches(evt)[0];                                      
    xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
    yDown = firstTouch.clientY;                                      
};                                                
                                                                         
function handleTouchMove(evt) {
    if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
        return;
    }

    var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
    var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

    var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
    var yDiff = yDown - yUp;
                                                                         
    if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
        if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
            /* right swipe */ 
        } else {
            /* left swipe */
        }                       
    } else {
        if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
          console.log('Swipe up');
          window.scroll({
          top: window.scrollY + window.innerHeight,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        });
        } else { 
          console.log('Swipe down');
            /* up swipe */
          window.scroll({
            top: window.scrollY - window.innerHeight,
            behavior: 'smooth',
          });
        }                                                                 
    }
    /* reset values */
    xDown = null;
    yDown = null;                                             
};
```

and this worked well until i tried to make it snap for non touch controls too and used this so it stopped working it is registering it but not scrolling

```
.containerMain {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slides {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: relative;
}
```

i would appreciate it if their is any work around or if there is anything wrong with my code
thanks in advance.